# mongoid, map/reduce best way to SUM vote?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

counting SUM vote by member in a large data. I want to show SUM vote all memember in a Event (in this question I not use Event model) .

TO GET ALL MEMBER SUM VOTE

First I using map/reduce to find sum vote each member. #=> name result: 'sum_vote'

Then I insert 'member a' with 6 new votes and 'member b' with 2 new votes.

I not want to read all data again because it too large.

I try:(IN 2 CASE I USE CACHE Object RESULT)

1. run map/reduce with option query is member_id = member_a.id AND option out:{merge:'sum_vote'}.  And member_b do it, too
2. when 1 vote insert , I update result 'sum_vote' by find by key _id(='member_id' ) then +1 to it value.

How are you do it? Please share me some issue. THanks :D

Answer (score 0):

In map/reduce have output type: 'reduce' . It exactly what I need.

Just run second map/reduce with option:query and set out:{reduce: 'sum_vote'}

Thank for your attention